# I accepted an arrange marriage proposal but after sometime his parents did 3 istikhara they are negative.. what to now? we really like each other now

Tags: sunnah

His parents sent his propsal to my parents ..it's completely arranged ..but after getting to know each other we really fell in love.His parents got insecure  as he earns really well and spends all on them so they don't want him attached to anyone else..They keep finding ways to end this arrangement..now they did 3 istikhara that came negative..it is necessary to follow them.

Comment: What do you mean when you say the istikhara "came negative"?

Comment: His parents said they consulted different molana and all of them said that istikhara wasn't right.This match is not suitable for ur son

Comment: "His parents got insecure as he earns really well and spends all on them so they don't want him attached to anyone else" ... this is slander and it indicates that perhaps their hesitation is right.

Comment: @UmH How can this be slander when no name is given?

Comment: I read about you and your parents, and the parents of your (proposed?) husband. I find something (someone) is lacking. What does HE say about it?

Comment: First of all even if other opinion among scholars exist. The two people who should perform istikhara are the concerned ones. For some scholars istikhara by a third party is meaningless and doesn't count at all. Further a man can marry himself without the consent of his parents, but it would be better to convince them.